# How to program condition after login or signup? (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, conditional-statements

I'm a beginner in flutter, I'm working on App for children's books if their age between 3-6 they will go directly to a specific library.

and if they are above 6 years they will go to another library..

How can I program it as a condition after login or signup?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can say "if (age > 3 && age < 6){ Navigaor.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPageScreen()))} else{ other page}

Answer (score 0):

You have to see this [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) first.

However, here is your answer. You can write this logic after your login signup successful response:

```
//.....
if(age > 3 && age <= 6) {
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstRoute()),  //first library
 );
}
if(age > 6) {
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),  //second library
 );
}
//.....
```